# CodeIgniter project very slow

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-hmvc

I am busy with a CI project using CI3 & HMVC. I work during office hours at work, then take it home for weekend & after work development. Using the two machines has been working for a long time. Monday morning, as normal I tried continuing from my weekend/home code and suddenly the project is super slow on my work machine but the machine has not changed. It runs Suse Linux (php 5.6). I wait forever for pages to load.

The exact same code works perfectly at home. when I look at the log after trying to access just one page:

```
INFO - 2016-08-02 09:44:23 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-02 09:46:30 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2016-08-02 09:46:30 --> Total execution time: 127.3685
```

One page takes almost two minutes to load.

Comment: Oh sorry, I made your machine a little slower. I thought you wanted to work a little slower, my bad. In all seriousness, how are we supposed to help? The machine is the cause. Something hogs the ressources. Good luck with that.

Comment: Oops I should have tagged apache too! and Tumbleweed :)

Answer (score 1):

Speed Up CodeIgniter Please Checkout Some Points

1. Compress HTML output
2. Enable Cache functions
3. Enable Gzip Compression

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered what was wrong with my CI application. I have a JSON file that is used to store settings for each module. As soon as I remove the JSON file, the application is faster. I am still not sure why this is not a problem on my home PC.